# clang, libtooling add new canonical builtin data type

Tags: c++, c, types, clang, libclang

In a program using libtooling, is there a way to make some types recognized as "built-in type" ?
For example, I'd like to make int16_t, uint32_t etc. recognized as canonical built-in types rather than it's typedef to short, unsigned etc.

Comment: Why do you want to do it?

Comment: To list global variables to monitore an embedded device. But I need to have fixed-length types.
And to avoid to manage typedefs etc. I'd prefer that the compiler sees these types as built-in types, I don't care about the errors generated on the redefinitions of these types.

Comment: What did you mean by *recognized as "built-in type"* ?

Comment: like in clang doc : 
"BuiltinType - This class is used for builtin types like 'int'. Builtin types are always canonical and have a literal name field."
http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1BuiltinType.html

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to specify it is for a program using libtooling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at `".../llvm/tools/clang/include/clang/AST/BuiltinTypes.def"`, then that would declare the builtin types like `int` and `long long`. It's not entirely straight forward tho'. You will need to modify quite a bit of code, for example there are portions of type definitions in `".../llvm/tools/clang/lib/Sema/Sema.cpp"` and `".../llvm/tools/clang/lib/AST/Type.cpp"`. If you grep for `Int128` (good choice as clang itself doesn't use that [much] in itself, as opposed to for example `size_t`), you will see that it turns up in a lot of places. You'd have to cover all (or at least most) of those places with additional code to introduce new types of your own making.

I would say that it's probably much easier to do something like `clang -include cstdint myprog.cpp`. In other words, make sure that the `#include <cstdint>` [or your own version of the same kind of file] is done behind the scenes in the compiler - you could add this to your driver in your own code too.

Comment: It seems quite hard (I mean long to do) and modify the sources of the lib doesn't really enjoy me... ^^ Is there another way to add canonicals type (at runtime) before parsing ?

Comment: Like I said, you can make clang read some source file (like an include file) before the actual source. I have to go to work now, but I can look up how that works when I'm back in front of my home computer tonight.

Comment: That is what I did, using a custom stdint.h defining the types as structs like : typedef struct {} int8_t etc. But it's quite auwkward...